# CSS3 and Timing Transitions in intervals as tool tips

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, timing

I have tooltips set up in divs and need to use CSS to time them in and out of focus onClick, like a tutorial.  Anyone know how to do this?

Chris

Comment: what do you mean time them in and out? Have you tried anything?

Comment: Eric,  I haven't tried anything yet.  What I am trying to accomplish is  onClick, 10 tooltips begin in sequential order, each one fades in, hangs out for 5 seconds, and then disappears while the next one in order fades in, and then disappears - and so on.

Comment: total duration is probably 40 sec. or so.